# Rollback issue with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am following [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) tutorial but have modified the POM.xml to use version 3.1.0.RELEASE of Spring Data Neo4j. I am experiencing a problem where the graph database does not seem to be instantiated correctly. The only code modification I did from the tutorial code was to replace the deprecated `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` API with the `GraphDatabaseService` API in `Application.java`. Any help would be appreciated.

*UPDATE*
This issue with the EmbdeedGraphDatabase is fixed. Now the issue is with rollback a transaction.

**Application.java**

```
package com.me.nosql.neo4j.hello;


import java.io.File;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Application() {
        setBasePackage("com/me/nosql/neo4j/hello");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("accessingdataneo4j.db");
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Person greg = new Person("Greg");
        Person roy = new Person("Roy");
        Person craig = new Person("Craig");

        System.out.println("Before linking up with Neo4j...");
        for (Person person : new Person[]{greg, roy, craig}) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }

        try (Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService().beginTx()) {
            personRepository.save(greg);
            personRepository.save(roy);
            personRepository.save(craig);

            greg = personRepository.findByName(greg.name);
            greg.worksWith(roy);
            greg.worksWith(craig);
            personRepository.save(greg);

            roy = personRepository.findByName(roy.name);
            roy.worksWith(craig);
            // We already know that roy works with greg
            personRepository.save(roy);

            // We already know craig works with roy and greg

            tx.success();
        }

        System.out.println("Lookup each person by name...");
        for (String name : new String[]{greg.name, roy.name, craig.name}) {
            System.out.println(personRepository.findByName(name));
        }

        System.out.println("Looking up who works with Greg...");
        for (Person person : personRepository.findByTeammatesName("Greg")) {
            System.out.println(person.name + " works with Greg.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("accessingdataneo4j.db"));
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Error Message**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:637)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:652)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at com.me.nosql.neo4j.hello.Application.main(Application.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to mark transaction as rollback only.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.failure(TopLevelTransaction.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext.close(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:59)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.close(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:33)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$super$close(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$close$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$close$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$close$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:149)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.close(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$close$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:65)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$close$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:63)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$close$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:63)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator.translateException(ClosingIterator.scala:70)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator.close(ClosingIterator.scala:62)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:92)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:166)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.PipeExecutionResult$$anon$1.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:74)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
    at com.me.nosql.neo4j.hello.Application.run(Application.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:634)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:93)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar problem and found the hint for the solution here (http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/).
I needed to add the constructor like this:

```
public Application() {
    setBasePackage("name/of/the/base/package");
}
```

The example ran, created the db and performed queries, all except the last ("Looking up who works with Greg..."). The error was:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to mark transaction as rollback only.
```

I managed to resolve this by wrapping the call in the transaction, just like that:

```
    Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();
    try {
        //Do all the work
        tx.success();
    } finally {
        tx.close();
    }
```

After then, everything worked fine for me.

EDIT: In order to make all transactions persist in DB I changed the following lines to

```
    try (Transaction tx = graphDatabase().beginTx()) {
        System.out.println("Lookup each person by name...");
        for (String name : new String[]{greg.name, roy.name, craig.name}) {
            System.out.println(personRepository.findByName(name));
        }
        tx.success();
    }

    try (Transaction tx = graphDatabase().beginTx()) {
        System.out.println("Looking up who works with Greg...");
        for (PersonJ person : personRepository.findByTeammatesName("Greg")) {
            System.out.println(person.name + " works with Greg.");
        }
        tx.success();
    }
```

Comment: hey, thanks for this! I've got the application storing the data in Neo4j now. However, I am facing the last problem you describe in your post: `Failed to mark transaction for as rollback only`. I have posted my updated code in the original post. Can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: I edited my original answer with the changes I made to the example

Comment: Got it! Cheers @Misha.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you would like to check :

1. `new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "accessingdataneo4j.db" );` Check if the path to the db is correct . Try with an absolute address.
2. Check if you aren't running the GraphDb instance somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
@Autowired
GraphDatabase graphDatabase;
```

And use the bean-method instead:

```
graphDatabaseService()
// or
graphDatabase()
```

Try to use `CommandlineRunner` as a bean and inject the dependency there. Spring doesn't inject beans that are declared in **this** configuration into the same config instance.